# How do you manage your zsh aliases?

Tags: terminal, zsh, alias

I guess I should just put all my alises in the `~/.zshrc`, correct? Or are there other places that's a better fit for personal alises?

Also wondering how you manage your list of aliases as you move between machines?

Comment: I put them in my `~/.zprofile` _file_ and copy it as needed to other machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I choose as a solution. I found this helps keep my initial .zshrc file free of clutter.

Place the aliases in their own file, ie: .zsh_aliases. You can also create a file for other things, like app shortcuts.

From there, just add a line in your .zshrc like the following;

```
source ~/.zsh_aliases
```

Feel free to reference any file that you might create. They will be included in each session. When moving to another machine, I just copy the files over and add them.

Comment: I feel since this would become a housing for aliases; that said, a general instantiation of just `~/.alias` as it would serve best that way to maintain agnostic to the shell being used; no? 
I'd love to know your view on this general namespace implementation?

Comment: My thought was, by naming it .zsh_aliases, it would separate from my .tcsh_aliases or anything else. I would also know what it is and for what shell it's for. (I still have older bash and tcsh shell code to port over.)